# Postgres 9.6 function performing poorly compared to straight sql

Tags: postgresql

I have this function, and it works, it gives the most recent `b` record.

```
create or replace function most_recent_b(the_a a) returns b as $$
    select distinct on (c.a_id) b.*
    from c 
    join b on b.c_id = c.id
    where c.a_id = the_a.id 
    order by c.a_id, b.date desc
$$ language sql stable;
```

This runs ~5000ms with real data. V.S. the following which runs in 500ms

```
create or replace function most_recent_b(the_a a) returns b as $$
    select distinct on (c.a_id) b.*
    from c 
    join b on b.c_id = c.id
    where c.a_id = 1347 
    order by c.a_id, b.date desc
$$ language sql stable;
```

The only difference being that I've hard coded `a.id` with a value `1347` instead of using its param value.

Also running this query without a function  also gives me speeds around 500ms

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6, so the query planner failing in functions results I see suggested elsewhere shouldn't apply to me right?

I'm sure its not the query itself that is the issue, as this is my third iteration at it, different techniques to get this result all result in the same slow down when inside a function.

As requested by @laurenz-albe

Result of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) with constant

```
Unique  (cost=60.88..60.89 rows=3 width=463) (actual time=520.117..520.122 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=14555
  ->  Sort  (cost=60.88..60.89 rows=3 width=463) (actual time=520.116..520.120 rows=9 loops=1)
        Sort Key: b.date DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB
        Buffers: shared hit=14555
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=13.71..60.86 rows=3 width=463) (actual time=386.848..520.083 rows=9 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (b.c_id = c.id)
              Buffers: shared hit=14555
              ->  Seq Scan on b (cost=0.00..46.38 rows=54 width=459) (actual time=25.362..519.140 rows=51 loops=1)
                    Filter: b_can_view(b.*)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 112
                    Buffers: shared hit=14530
              ->  Hash  (cost=13.67..13.67 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.880..0.880 rows=10 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=25
                    ->  Subquery Scan on c  (cost=4.21..13.67 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.222..0.872 rows=10 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=25
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on c c_1  (cost=4.21..13.64 rows=3 width=2276) (actual time=0.221..0.863 rows=10 loops=1)
                                Recheck Cond: (a_id = 1347)
                                Filter: c_can_view(c_1.*)
                                Heap Blocks: exact=4
                                Buffers: shared hit=25
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on c_a_id_c_number_idx  (cost=0.00..4.20 rows=8 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=10 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (a_id = 1347)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=1
Execution time: 520.256 ms
```

And this is the result after running six times with the parameter being passed ( it was exactly six times as you predicted :) )
Slow query;

```
Unique  (cost=57.07..57.07 rows=1 width=463) (actual time=5040.237..5040.243 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=145325
  ->  Sort  (cost=57.07..57.07 rows=1 width=463) (actual time=5040.237..5040.240 rows=9 loops=1)
        Sort Key: b.date DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB
        Buffers: shared hit=145325
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.14..57.06 rows=1 width=463) (actual time=912.354..5040.195 rows=9 loops=1)
              Join Filter: (c.id = b.c_id)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 501
              Buffers: shared hit=145325
              ->  Index Scan using c_a_id_idx on c (cost=0.14..9.45 rows=1 width=2276) (actual time=0.378..1.171 rows=10 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (a_id = $1)
                    Filter: c_can_view(c.*)
                    Buffers: shared hit=25
              ->  Seq Scan on b (cost=0.00..46.38 rows=54 width=459) (actual time=24.842..503.854 rows=51 loops=10)
                    Filter: b_can_view(b.*)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 112
                    Buffers: shared hit=145300
Execution time: 5040.375 ms
```

Its worth noting that I have some strict row level security involved, and I suspect this is why these queries are both slow, however, one is 10 times slower than the other.

I've changed my original table names hopefully my search and replace was good here.

Comment: why not `function most_recent_b(the_a_id int) returns b` ?..

Comment: @VaoTsun same slow down with any param type.

Comment: I think I might be running into this issue https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/8185.1477432701@sss.pgh.pa.us#8185.1477432701@sss.pgh.pa.us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expensive part of your query execution is the filter `b_can_view(b.*)`, which must come from your row level security definition.

The fast execution:

```
Seq Scan on b (cost=0.00..46.38 rows=54 width=459)
              (actual time=25.362..519.140 rows=51 loops=1)
  Filter: b_can_view(b.*)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 112
  Buffers: shared hit=14530
```

The slow execution:

```
Seq Scan on b (cost=0.00..46.38 rows=54 width=459)
              (actual time=24.842..503.854 rows=51 loops=10)
  Filter: b_can_view(b.*)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 112
  Buffers: shared hit=145300
```

The difference is that the scan is executed 10 times in the slow case (`loops=10`) and touches 10 times as many data blocks.

When using the generic plan, PostgreSQL underestimates how many rows in `c` will satisfy the condition `c.a_id = $1`, because it doesn't know that the actual value is 1347, which is more frequent than average.

Since PostgreSQL thinks there will be at most one row from `c`, it chooses a nested loop join with a sequential scan of `b` on the inner side.

Now two problems combine:

1. Calling function `b_can_view` takes over 3 milliseconds per row (which PostgreSQL doesn't know), which accounts for the half second that a sequential scan of the 163 rows takes.
2. There are actually 10 rows found in `c` instead of the predicted 1, so table `b` is scanned 10 times, and you end up with a query duration of 5 seconds.

So what can you do?

- Tell PostgreSQL how expensive the `b_can_view` is. Use `ALTER TABLE` to set the `COST` for that function to 1000 or 10000 to reflect reality. That alone will not be enough to get a faster plan, since PostgreSQL thinks that it has to execute a single sequential scan anyway, but it is a good thing to give the optimizer correct data.
- Create an index on `b(c_id)`. That will enable PostgreSQL to avoid a sequential scan of `b`, which it will try to do once it is aware how expensive the function is.

Also, try to make the function `b_can_view` cheaper. That will make your experience so much better.

Comment: I have adapted the answer to the additional information.